# How to write normal sql queries inside controller in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to know how to write down normal sql queries inside laravel controller?

```
SELECT 

       vd.photo,
       CONCAT(vd.firstName," ",vd.lastName) as FullName,
       v.photo,
       v.vehicleModel,
       sr.tripType,
       sr.schoolTime,
       GROUP_CONCAT( rs.schoolName SEPARATOR ' ') as School_Name,
       GROUP_CONCAT( cp.checkPoint SEPARATOR ' ') as CheckPoints

FROM 

     vehicles v,
     school_van_routes sr,
     routes_schools rs,
     school_route_check_points cp,
     van_drivers vd,
     van_owners vo

WHERE

      v.numberPlate=sr.selectVehicle 
      AND sr.id=rs.routeId 
      AND sr.id= cp.routeId
      AND v.vanOwnerEmail=vo.email 
      AND vo.email =vd.email

GROUP BY v.id
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

If you want to execute raw SQL rather than using a query builder, you can try:

`$results = DB::select("SELECT * ..")`

More here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#running-queries

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can convert your sql query.

```
$result = DB::table(DB::raw('vehicles v, school_van_routes sr, routes_schools rs, school_route_check_points cp, van_drivers vd, van_owners vo')) 
        ->select(DB::raw("vd.photo, CONCAT(vd.firstName,' ',vd.lastName) as FullName, v.photo, v.vehicleModel, sr.tripType, sr.schoolTime, GROUP_CONCAT( rs.schoolName SEPARATOR ' ') as School_Name, GROUP_CONCAT( cp.checkPoint SEPARATOR ' ') as CheckPoints"))
        ->whereRaw('v.numberPlate=sr.selectVehicle')
        ->whereRaw('sr.id=rs.routeId')
        ->whereRaw('sr.id= cp.routeId')
        ->whereRaw('v.vanOwnerEmail=vo.email')
        ->whereRaw('vo.email =vd.email')
        ->groupBy('v.id', 'v.photo', 'vd.photo', 'v.vehicleModel', 'sr.tripType', 'sr.schoolTime')
        ->get();

dd($result);
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '') as School_Name, GROUP_CONCA' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: @GayalSeneviratne try now.

Comment: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'schoolvan.vd.photo' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select vd.photo, CONCAT(vd.firstName,' ',vd.lastName) as FullName, v.photo, v.vehicleModel, sr.tripType, sr.schoolTime, GROUP_CONCAT( rs.schoolName SEPARATOR ' ') as School_Name, GROUP_CONCAT( cp.checkPoint SEPARATOR ' ') as CheckPoints from vehicles v, school_van_routes sr, routes_schools rs, school_route_check_points cp, van_drivers vd, van_owners vo where v.numberPlate=sr.selectVehicle and sr.id=rs.routeId and sr.id= cp.routeId and v.vanOwnerEmail=vo.email and vo.email =vd.email

Comment: group by `v`.`id`)

Comment: you need to include rest of the aggregated fields in groupBy clause.. like `->groupBy('v.id', 'v.photo', 'vd.photo', 'v.vehicleModel', 'sr.tripType', 'sr.schoolTime')`

Comment: @GayalSeneviratne does this help?

Comment: What is the issue now?